# What happens to the .env file when I build my react app with npm run build?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, production, npm-scripts, dotenv

The build version is working perfectly but can't see where it stores the environment variables. Are they hidden or visible to everyone ?

Answer (score 0):

The Create React App (Webpack) build process "folds" the environment variables into constants in the source, and things are bundled as per usual after that.

They're visible to anyone who looks at your app's script files in their browser's View Source or Inspector views.